# Deleting objects from a model in Swing

Tags: java, swing, defaultlistmodel

I am working with a swing GUI for a grading system project I am doing. I originally found an issue with an NPE regarding deleting Student objects from the `DefaultListModel`, and I think I found the source. I ran two tests, one within the Controller Class, and the other the view.

```
DefaultListModel<Student> model = new DefaultListModel(); //declarations in Controller 

private TreeMap<String, Student> tm = new TreeMap();
```

Now, when I add a student using the JButton for adding, I ran the following test to make sure the Student was added to the TreeMap and ListModel.

```
private void handleAddButton(){
   fn = sv.firstName(); //return firstName from textArea
   ln = sv.lastName(); //return lastName from textArea
   Student s = new Student(ln, fn);
   model.addElement(s);
   tm.put(Student.makeStudentKey(fn, ln), s); 
   String grades = sv.getGrades(); //returns string of grades from textField
   sc = new Scanner(grades);
   while(sc.hasNext()){
       s.addGrade(sc.nextDouble()); //add grades to Student's grades ArrayList
   }
   sv.clearField();//clear textFields and area
   sv.setId(); //set NextID to be displayed in respective textField
   debug();
```

}

The Debug method:

```
 public void debug(){
    System.out.println(tm.size());
    for(Student s : tm.values()){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println(model.size());
}
```

Now when ran in the handleAddButton class given 1 student "test test", `debug` prints 1, student toString, 1. This is the method that runs debug in the View class, handling a Menu item to create a new file.

```
private void NewActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    int check = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want"
            + " to create a new file?", "New File", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    System.out.println(check);
    sc.debug();
    if(check == 0){
    sc.clearModel();
    sc.clearTm();
    sc.setListModel();
    }
```

when tested identically with one student, it returns 0 0, as if no students were added. `sv` is initialized, I just can't wrap my head around why this is happening, and its preventing me from being able to delete objects as well as clear the model

Comment: Have you tried using [DefaultListModel#removeElementAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#removeElementAt%28int%29)?

Comment: yes, it didn't work either.

Comment: The problem isn't you can't delete, but can't add? Sounds like you have variable shadowing problem, but without a runnable example, it's impossible to know

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but anything done within the View class acts like the TreeMap and Model are empty. I add within the Controller and it works, and I can remove and clear if I am within the Controller.